# Can I Branch Off the Current Branch?

Tags: git, git-branch, git-flow

- I am using gitflow within a company environment.
- I have a feature that has not yet been accepted into the origin development branch (I still need to write Unit Tests, etc).
- I would like to test the feasibility of an additional feature based upon my current feature.

I would like develop the additional feature and leave my current feature branch as is.  Can I create a new branch off of this feature branch?

What is the ideal workflow for this situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can I create a new branch off of this feature branch?

Yes.

> What is the ideal workflow for this situation?

Treat it like you would the rest of your workflow. Your feature branch acts as a highly localized "master branch". Branch off of it. Make your changes. Run the appropriate tests. Merge it back in. Then your feature branch will have everything it needs when it merges back into the actual master branch.